# Open new view in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, route-provider

I'm trying to handle the 'wheel click' and 'right-click > open in new tab/window' in order to load the targeted view in the new tab/window.

Let's say in one of my view, I have something like this :

```
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="h.changeView('projects')">Time Tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="h.changeView('requests')">Dashboard</a></li>
```

The `changeView()` function in my controller looks like this :

```
  this.changeView = function(viewPath) {
    $location.path(viewPath);
  };
```

And the route configuration like this :

```
// Routes configuration
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'requests/requestsList.html',
      controller: 'requestsController',
      controllerAs: 'r'
    })
    .when('/requests', {
      templateUrl: 'requests/requestsList.html',
      controller: 'requestsController',
      controllerAs: 'r'
    })
    .when('/projects', {
      templateUrl: 'projects/projectsList.html',
      controller: 'projectsController',
      controllerAs: 'p'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

How could I handle the displaying of a new view in  a different tab/window ?

Also, is there a syntax in my `$routeProvider` that allows me to combine the `/` and `/requests` in the same `when(...)` ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in a way which interacts with Angular, but normally you would put a real URL in `href`, and then the event handler function would read that value and use it to describe which content to dynamically load.

Comment: The url would point to a view, which is in my case only a part of the page to be loaded.

Comment: Then you're doing URLs wrong. The URL should point to the complete page (i.e. the complete page should be delivered by the server). When you change part of the content with JavaScript, you should use the History API (pushState & co) to update the URL to one where the server would deliver the page you just constructed piece by piece with JS.

Comment: I have a main page containing : `<div header></div> <ng-view></ng-view> <div footer></div>`. When I call `changeView()`, I only change the `<ng-view>`, I don't reload my header and footer. Is that a bad practice ?

Comment: That's the "When you change part of the content with JavaScript" part. That's fine. You just need to do the rest of it.

Answer (score -1):

Simple HTMl will help you there. Add in your HTML code a target="_blank"

Comment: This will result in opening my view in a new tab when left clicking on the element, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Ellone — More likely it would open `javascript:void()` in a new window.

Answer (score -1):

Try using $window service:

```
this.changeView = function(viewPath) {
  $window.open(viewPath, '_blank');
};
```

Comment: The question is asking how to open *the right content* in a new tab/window **when the user explicitly picks Open In New Tab/Window**, not when the link is clicked normally.